# Real part of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Consider the real part of the Riemann zeta function on the critical line. Are there any results for the number of zeros of this real function in the interval [0,T]?

Answer (score 3):

Zeroes of the real part of the Riemann zeta function have been studied by

- [Gonek and Ki](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2017.10.024) (2018): *Pair correlation of zeros of the real and imaginary parts of the Riemann zeta-function*
- [Korolev](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0001434615110322) (2015): *On the Horizontal Distribution of Zeros of the Functions Re ζ(s) and Im ζ(s)*
- [Ki](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2008.02.009) (2008): *On the zeros of sums of the Riemann zeta function*
- [Garaev](https://www.impan.pl/pl/wydawnictwa/czasopisma-i-serie-wydawnicze/acta-arithmetica/all/108/3/81985/on-vertical-zeros-of-re-zeta-s-and-im-zeta-s) (2003): *On vertical zeroes of $\Re\zeta(s)$ and $\Im\zeta(s)$*

Garaev proves that the number $N_A(T)$ of zeroes of the function $A(t)=\Re\zeta(\sigma_0+it)$ in the interval $(0,T)$ on the critical line $\sigma_0=1/2$ satisfies

[image]

The same holds for the number $N_B(T)$ of zeroes of $B(t)=\Im\zeta(\sigma_0+it)$. Gonek and Ki consider the statistical distribution of these zeroes, on vertical lines $a+it$ in the complex plane with $0<a\leq 1/2$. The distribution on horizontal lines is studied by Korolev.